# SDN4 Enum to String conversion fails

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have an entity class:

```
@Data
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=JSOGGenerator.class)

@NodeEntity(label="Person")
public class PersonNode  {
    @GraphId                       private @NonNull Long id;
    @Property(name="neo_ID")    private @NonNull Long ID;
    @Property(name="neo_name")     private @NonNull String name;
    @Property(name="neo_surname")  private @NonNull String surname;
    @Property(name="neo_spec")     private @NonNull String specialization;
    @Property(name="neo_gender")   private @NonNull @Convert(graphPropertyType = String.class)
                                                    Gender sex;
    @Property(name="neo_age")      private @NonNull Byte age;

    public PatientNode() {
    }
```

while the `Gender` type:

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE("M"), 
    FEMALE("F"), 
    UNKNOWN("");

    private final String gender;

    Gender(String sex){
        if (sex.toUpperCase().equals("F") || sex.toUpperCase().equals("M") )
            this.gender = sex.toUpperCase();
        else
            this.gender="";
    }

    String getGender(){
        return this.gender;
    }

    public static Gender toGender(String str){
        try {
            return valueOf(str.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return UNKNOWN;
        }
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.gender;
    }
}
```

I have added the:

```
@Bean
public ConversionService conversionService() {
    return new MetaDataDrivenConversionService(getSessionFactory().metaData());
}
```

To my `public class MyNeo4jConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration`
Now the issue is that when I try to read from the Neo4j with `GrpahRepositry<person>` default `findAll()` method I  get an error:

**Error Generated:**

> No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.String to type .server.infrastructure.persistence.utils.Gender

**1. What is the problem?**

**2. How to provide this simple conversion for SDN4 as the Neo4j does not support enum type?**

### EDIT:

The issue is still present. After changing my Neo4jConfiguration according to @Luanne hint it looks as follows:

```
package server.infrastructure.repositories.neo4j.config;

import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService;
import org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService;
import org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.MetaDataDrivenConversionService;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.Neo4jServer;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.RemoteServer;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "server.infrastructure.repositories.neo4j")

@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "server.services.neo4j")


public class MyNeo4jConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public static final int NEO4J_PORT=7474;
    public static final String USER_NAME="neo4j";
    public static final String USER_PASS="aaa";

    @Bean
    public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {

        return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:"+NEO4J_PORT, USER_NAME, USER_PASS);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        // with domain entity base package(s)
        return new SessionFactory("server.infrastructure.persistence.neo4j");
    }

    // needed for session in view in web-applications
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }

    // For enum / date / biginteger etc types in entities conversion
    @Bean
    public ConversionService conversionService() {
        ConversionService conversionService = new MetaDataDrivenConversionService(getSessionFactory().metaData());
        DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters((GenericConversionService) conversionService);

        return conversionService;
    }


}
```

I am using the following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>testing</groupId>
  <artifactId>serverT</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>serverMR</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>

      <!-- Generic properties -->
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

      <!-- Spring -->
      <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
      <spring-data.version>Gosling-RELEASE</spring-data.version>
      <spring-data-neo4j.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>

      <!-- Logging -->
      <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
      <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>
  </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- To run application with tomcat7:run -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>


  <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>

          <!-- For spring framework dependencies version compatibility -->
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
              <version>${spring.version}</version>
              <scope>import</scope>
              <type>pom</type>
          </dependency>

          <!-- For spring-data  dependencies version compatibility -->
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
              <version>${spring-data.version}</version>
              <scope>import</scope>
              <type>pom</type>
          </dependency>


    </dependencies>

  </dependencyManagement>


  <dependencies>

      <!-- hypermedia-driven REST web services on top of Spring Data infrastructure
            - version from spring-data-releasetrain
       -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Force newer version than spring-data-releasetrain -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>


      <!-- For autogeneration of getter/setter-->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <version>1.14.8</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- JUnit -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!--To run application with tomcat7:run force servlet 3.1 version to be used-->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!--To avoid circular JSON generation, the JSOGGenerator is used as id-generator in entities-->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.voodoodyne.jackson.jsog</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-jsog</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.1</version>
      </dependency>



  </dependencies>

</project>
```

However still the enum fails to covert with running `mvn tomcat7:run` and referring with controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/per")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list",
                    method = RequestMethod.GET,
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
                    )
    public List<PersonNode> getPersons){

        return personService.getList();
    }

}
```

and Service:

```
@Service

@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class PersonService implements FinderService<PersonNode> {

    private final @NonNull PersonNeo4JRepository personNeo4JRepository;

    public List<PersonNode> getList(){

        Iterable<PersonNode> iterablePer = personNeo4JRepository.findAll();
        List<PersonNode> perList =
                new ArrayList<>(IteratorUtil.asCollection(iterablePer));


        return  perList;
    }
```

and the PersonRepository

```
@Repository
public interface PersonNeo4JRepository extends GraphRepository<PersonNode>
```

to http://localhost:8080/rest/per/list:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building serverMR 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ serverMR >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ serverMR ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ serverMR ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ serverMR <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ serverMR ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/
[INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration at /home/mc/Dropbox/Projekty/Robocze/serverMR/target/tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: 
gru 17, 2015 2:46:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
gru 17, 2015 2:46:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
gru 17, 2015 2:46:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
gru 17, 2015 2:46:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
gru 17, 2015 2:46:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
14:46:33.960 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
14:46:34.035 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Dec 17 14:46:34 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
14:46:34.071 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/ApplicationContext.xml]
14:46:34.150 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/Neo4j-DataSources.xml]
14:46:34.521 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'myNeo4jConfiguration' of type [class server.infrastructure.repositories.neo4j.config.MyNeo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1830c4f2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
14:46:34.523 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor
14:46:34.818 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Starting Post-processing phase
14:46:34.818 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Building annotation class map
14:46:34.818 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Building interface class map for 6 classes
14:46:34.818 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Registering default type converters...
14:46:34.823 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Post-processing complete
14:46:34.823 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - 6 classes loaded in 16 milliseconds
14:46:35.094 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext - Neo4jMappingContext initialisation completed
14:46:35.211 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising PersistenceExceptionTranslator
14:46:35.214 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor
14:46:35.217 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising Neo4jTransactionManager
14:46:35.255 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1293 ms
14:46:35.285 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'MR.rest.api': initialization started
gru 17, 2015 2:46:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'MR.rest.api'
14:46:35.290 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'MR.rest.api-servlet': startup date [Thu Dec 17 14:46:35 CET 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
14:46:35.291 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringMVC/SpringMVC-RESTContext.xml]
14:46:35.519 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/per/list],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.util.List<server.infrastructure.persistence.neo4j.nodes.PersonNode> server.api.rest.controller.PersonController.getPersons()
14:46:35.701 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'MR.rest.api-servlet': startup date [Thu Dec 17 14:46:35 CET 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
14:46:35.758 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'MR.rest.api-servlet': startup date [Thu Dec 17 14:46:35 CET 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
14:46:35.857 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'MR.rest.api': initialization completed in 572 ms
gru 17, 2015 2:46:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
14:46:42.928 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising Neo4jSession
14:46:43.143 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Intercepted exception
gru 17, 2015 2:46:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MR.rest.api] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MappingException: Error mapping GraphModel to instance of server.infrastructure.persistence.neo4j.nodes.PersonNode] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant server.infrastructure.persistence.utils.Gender.M
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToEnumConverterFactory$StringToEnum.convert(StringToEnumConverterFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToEnumConverterFactory$StringToEnum.convert(StringToEnumConverterFactory.java:45)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterFactoryAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:425)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:35)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:176)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.MetaDataDrivenConversionService.convert(MetaDataDrivenConversionService.java:102)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.typeconversion.ProxyAttributeConverter.toEntityAttribute(ProxyAttributeConverter.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.entityaccess.FieldWriter.write(FieldWriter.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.writeProperty(GraphEntityMapper.java:164)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.setProperties(GraphEntityMapper.java:129)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.mapNodes(GraphEntityMapper.java:110)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:94)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:69)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.SessionResponseHandler.loadAll(SessionResponseHandler.java:181)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:69)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:99)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.loadAll(Neo4jSession.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.loadAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryImpl.findAll(GraphRepositoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryImpl.findAll(GraphRepositoryImpl.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:432)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at server.services.neo4j.PersonService.getList(PersonService.java:30)
    at server.api.rest.controller.PersonController.getPersons(PersonController.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to use the converter provided by Spring, you also need to register them with the ConversionService.

For example,

```
 @Bean
    public ConversionService conversionService() {
        ConversionService conversionService = new MetaDataDrivenConversionService(getSessionFactory().metaData());
        DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters((GenericConversionService) conversionService);

        return conversionService;
    }
```

and then it'll be picked up and used.

**Update based on additional info provided**

The stacktrace shows that the converter is being invoked. But it's trying to find an enum with value "M", and it can't find one. Note that the `StringToEnumConverterFactory` calls `valueOf` on your enum (see class javadoc `Converts from a String to a {@link java.lang.Enum} by calling {@link Enum#valueOf(Class, String)}.`)
The value stored in the graph will be your enum name `MALE` which will convert back fine.

So, does this mean you have data in your graph with `neo_gender`=`M` ? If so, perhaps you need to clean that up, or provide a custom converter capable of handling both cases.

Comment: When I change the `conversionService` the way you proposed I now got the following error:
`Error mapping GraphModel to instance of server.infrastructure.persistence.neo4j.nodes.PersonNode] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant server.infrastructure.persistence.utils.Gender.M`

Comment: I've written a test and Im unable to reproduce this. Can you supply the full exception stacktrace and the version of SDN 4 you're using? Or open an issue at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH with code + exception or test case, thanks

Comment: Please refer to the main question as I have edited the main question to provide the requested remaining code, pom.xml and full exception stacktrace. I have forced the SDN4 version due to the release train  Gosling is not supporting it. (Hopper will hopefully soon cover this though)
If this is not enough please point what can I do to provide you additional information.

Comment: Yes node were storing the 'M' value and I thought it would covert to `MALE` correctly. So I will provide my own converter (as proposed [http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_conversion-custom])
BTW. The `conversionService` implementation that I have previously used were based on the [documentation of SDN4)[http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_spring_s_conversionservice] shouldn't it contain the registering call which you have mentioned and I have missed due to lack in docs?

Comment: Cool. The docs do mention that SDN 4 will use converters registered with the conversion service so that is the assumption. The example provided above just one way of doing that. Please accept the answer if it solves the problem, thanks!

Comment: I understand, Thank you very much for your assistance. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where an enum property was not converted and was set to null when the object was loaded.

The fix for me was two-fold,

1. add the `ConversionService` configuration as mentioned by the accepted answer, and
2. add the package containing the enum to the `SessionFactory` config.

   ```
   @Override
   @Bean
   public SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
   {
       // With domain entity base package(s) which must include enums 
       // that are referenced by @NodeEntity classes.
       return new SessionFactory("package.containing.node.entities", 
                                 "package.containing.enum.classes");
   }
   ```